# Flutter use "body" without Scaffold, possible?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Wanna understand something... Is possible use parameters like "body" and "child" without Scaffold? Or any idea for a clean code or better method? That's my main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'background_image_task-9.dart';
import 'hyperlink.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Blumax',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: myColour
      ),
      home: BackgroundImage(
        body: Center(
          child: Hyperlink("www.test.com"),
        )
        ),
    );
  }
}

const MaterialColor myColour = const MaterialColor(
```

That's my background_image_task-9.dart for background image

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BackgroundImage extends StatelessWidget{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text('Blumax', style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontFamily: 'DancingScript',
            fontSize: 40
          ),),
          centerTitle: false,
        ),
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("assets/blumax.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

And that's my hyperlink.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class Hyperlink extends StatelessWidget {
  final String _url;
  final String _text;

  Hyperlink(this._url, this._text);

  _launchURL() async {
    if (await canLaunch(_url)) {
      await launch(_url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $_url';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Text(
        _text,
        style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
      ),
      onTap: _launchURL,
    );
  }
}
```

Of course "body" and "child" are not accepted, because without Scaffold in "home" they are not defined. I can't change "home: BeackgroundImage" because i use for change background image with another .dart file . The "hyperlink.dart" is ok, working, but can't resolve that in main. Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: What is `BackgroundImage`?

Comment: I add the rest of the code, sorry

Comment: Well, in your BackgroundImage you can do: Widget body; and  in the constructor BackgroundImage({this.body}); for example.. You cand pass a widget in parameters.

Comment: @ClaudioCastro can you write me an example code? Or link it? I dont understand how

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/ccastroelo/scaffout

Comment: @ClaudioCastro thanks, but when i put "body:" the second one, an error appear "Expected to find ']'.dart(expected_token)" the "]" is after body, like your example

Comment: My code is running, I suggest you download it and have a look. To do what you wanted I used a Stack () that expects a widget array. The first is your container. The second is the body that is passed by parameter. Another thing, Your hyperlink is expecting 2 parameters, in your code only one is being passed.

Comment: Now is working, as you say, is expecting two parameters, i just insert one. Thanks!